# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in CRUD REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong since I'm new to all this concepts. If there is anything else that you'll like me to add just let me know.

I am trying to GET/POST the API in postman but I got error.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo'
const routers = require('../public/app')

const app = express()

app.use('/app', routers)

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true})
const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', () => {
   console.log('connected..')

})

app.use(express.json)

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started')
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router() 
const schemas = require('../models/schema')

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const receive = await schemas.find()
        res.json(receive)
    }catch(err){
        res.send('Error ' + err)
    }
})

router.post ('/', async(req, res) => {
    const send = new schemas({
        name: req.body.name,
        tech: req.body.tech,
    })

    try{
        const a1 = await send.save()
        res.json(a1)

    }catch(err){
       res.send('Error')
   }
})

 module.exports = router
```

schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true  
    },
    tech: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('schemas', schema)
```

this is an error

PS D:\node\crudjs> npm run dev

> crudjs@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon src/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
server started
connected..
D:\node\crudjs\public\app.js:16

name: req.body.name,
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at D:\node\crudjs\public\app.js:16:24
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at router (D:\node\crudjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Node.js v18.9.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Error message is quite obvious. There is no property `body` in `req` object. You can try to add: `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Ya! I tried but it didn't work for me